# Messed working directory tree at Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, osx-yosemite

I tried to find a answer for this, but I couldn't. So, sorry if there is a duplicate.
I'm working with Sublime Text 3 at Mac OS X (Yosemite 10.10.1) and sometimes this happen.

[image: Messed directory tree]

It's not a big problem, but it's annoying. Anyone else had this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Have this same problem right now... Running El Capitan